# Android Studio with Subversion on Windows works fine, but keeps throwing errors

Tags: svn, android-studio

My environment is Android Studio, Win 7, Subversion.

Everything works fine, however, everything related to subversion, like commits, updates keeps throwing errors as if it didn't work.

But it worked! When I commit a change, my colleagues can update their files and my changes will be there. It's just these annoying random messages.

This is the message when I update the repository: `Error:svn: E155000: Failed to add directory 'app/build/intermediates/res/debug': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists` but it does work, because I can see the changes from my colleagues.

This is when I try to check in `Error:Warning: post-commit FS processing had error 'attempt to write a readonly database'.` So weird... it still working fine!

What's happening and how can I get rid of these error messages?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Provide the messages please

Comment: This is the message when I update the repository: "Error:svn: E155000: Failed to add directory 'app/build/intermediates/res/debug': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists" but it does work, because I can see the changes from my colleagues.

Comment: This is when I try to check in "Error:Warning: post-commit FS processing had error 'attempt to write a readonly database'." So weird... it still working fine!

Comment: Checkout a new working copy to new location and make sure that you have Write access to the directory.

Comment: Ok, I've checked out many times today, re imported the project to a new repository folder and manage to get rid of the update message. The commit error is still happening, and is still working. My colleagues can see my changes. So, if it's working, I don't think the problem is permissions, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi @bahrep, I finally manage to fix the problem... basically I had to give permissions to write in the subversion server file rep-cache.db. Not sure why it would work for my colleagues and not for me though... maybe because they are Linux machines and I'm Windows. Anyway hope this helps someone and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going on the subversion server and adding permissions to write for the group on the file:

/home/svn/repos/db/rep-cache.db

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add certain files to the ignore list of SVN.

Read up about the ignoring files part.

I have added the following items in my .gitignore, it should be the same for SVN:

```
gradle
.idea
*.iml
build
.DS_Store -- only in macs
```

Comment: Hi @55597, I finally manage to fix the problem... basically I had to give permissions to write in the subversion server file rep-cache.db. Not sure why it would work for my colleagues and not for me though... maybe because they are Linux machines and I'm Windows. Anyway hope this helps someone and thanks for your help.